# Query and select data from the test2 and test3 tables from MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I am looking to get the data from the `test2` and `test3` tables to show up on the webpage, but I keep seeing a blank screen.

```php
$query = "INSERT INTO test2,test3 VALUES(' ','$title','$stdate','$endate',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','$fileName','$fileSize','$fileType',' ','$desc',' ','$postuser')";

} } }
else {   
$query = "INSERT INTO test2,test3 VALUES(' ','$title','$stdate','$endate',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','$fileName','$fileSize','$fileType',' ','$desc',' ','$postuser')";

}    
mysql_query($query) or die('Error, query failed.         '. mysql_error());

}   

$query4=" SELECT * FROM test2,test3";
```

Comment: Do you really want to "get the data from the test2 and test3 *database*". Aren't  test2 and test3 *tables* instead ?

Comment: yes they are tables from the same database sorry

Answer (score 1):

Your approach feels inherently wrong, but nevertheless, here is corrected code:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO test2 VALUES(' ','$title','$stdate','$endate',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','$fileName','$fileSize','$fileType',' ','$desc',' ','$postuser')";

} } }
else {   
$query = "INSERT INTO test3 VALUES(' ','$title','$stdate','$endate',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','$fileName','$fileSize','$fileType',' ','$desc',' ','$postuser')";

}    
mysql_query($query) or die('Error, query failed.         '. mysql_error());

}   

$query4="SELECT * FROM test2 UNION ALL SELECT * FROM test3";
```

Comment: for this code $query = "UPDATE `test2` should I use $query = "UPDATE `test2`, `test3`

Comment: "This code worked for me thanks" ?!? It is quite surprising while I see that in the code: `INSERT INTO test2,test3 ...` : last time I checked, MySQL didn't support *multi-table* `INSERT` (whereas it *is* supported for `UPDATE`). Please check and see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html for supported `INSERT` syntax

Comment: @SylvainLeroux Sorry, missed that one. I'll tell you why the code worked for HIM - he had those values in `table2` and `table3` already, so `SELECT * FROM test2 UNION ALL SELECT * FROM test3` worked as he expected.

Comment: @user2512457 Come again? I can't see any UPDATE-s here, what part are you talking about?

Answer (score 0):

How about this one

```
$dh = mysql_connect('localhost','root','') or die(mysql_error());

$db1 = mysql_select_db('test2',$dh);
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tableFromTest2",$db1);

$db2 = mysql_select_db('test3',$dh);
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tableFromTest3",$db2);

mysql_close($dh);
```

or

```
mysql_connect('localhost','root','') or die(mysql_error());

mysql_query("USE test2");
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tableFromTest2");

mysql_query("USE test3");
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tableFromTest3");

mysql_close($dh);
```

Comment: Where would I place this code at in reference to what I posted above. how should it look?

Comment: refer to $db1 or $db2 just like what i did

Comment: errorError, query failed. Column 'fname' in field list is ambiguous. what does this mean

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want a simple union:

```
SELECT * FROM test2
UNION
SELECT * FROM test3
```

assuming the table structure of test2 and test3 are similar (as they are in your sample code).

Of course since you're inserting it twice (once into each table), you might want to get it back twice - so use UNION ALL. Also you can play with ORDER BY and DISTINCT Optimization.

Comment: `UNION` if you want to remove duplicates. `UNION ALL` if you want to keep them.

Comment: Where would I place this code at in reference to what I posted above. how should it look?

Comment: here: $query4 = "(SELECT * FROM test2) UNION (SELECT * FROM test3)";

Comment: @SylvainLeroux is correct - and also suggested I remove the parentheses which was also a good idea :)

Comment: @SylvainLeroux how can I use the code for both tables $query = "UPDATE `test2`, `test3`